# Wordpress Smart slider Plugin is not working

Tags: wordpress

Our Website link : https://www.opportunityclinic.org/

In the home page we have smart slider . Previously it was working. When we inspect home page of our website we are getting error. We are attaching an image regarding this issue. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH14E.png)

Comment: Are you using any caching or minify plugin?

Comment: No I am not using.

Comment: have you installed any new plugins after that its stopped working? cz it looks like some other js is interfering with smart slider's js

Comment: Analyze & Repair option is there besides deactivate option.

Comment: you can try that.. may be it will give you the info about which js is causing problem

Comment: OK thanks I am looking it.

Comment: you can post the response  and update the question.

Comment: Analyze & Repair is redirected to Welcome to smart slider 3 page